# If a setState holds an object, how to only listen and re-render based on only some properties of the object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```js
const [var, set_var] = useState({prop_1: 1, prop_2: 2})
```

How to do this essentially:

```
useEffect(() =>, [var.prop_1])

useEffect(() =>, [var.prop_2])
```

Comment: What you did there it will work the way you want. 
Another approach is to destructure the property of the object you want to listen to, outside of the useEffect and use that destructured property in dependency array

Comment: This isn't very useful though because your component will already re-render whenever the object is changed. That's what your `set_var` does. It updates the state and re-renders your component.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the properties you want to listen to from an array and add them to the `[]` in the useEffect deps.

```
const ages = students.map((s) => s.age);

useEffect(() => {
    // Now you can listen to any cahnges in the array Object for "age" property!
    console.info("ages", ages);
}, [ages]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/listen-re-render-on-array-object-state-change-2kd49k?file=/src/App.js)